# How to write an efficient code div.innerHTML like code in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

If i need to change a small html dynamically on or before a success or error callback of ajax in html I do

```
document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML("<img />");
```

in jQuery also i can do

```
jQuery("#xyz").html("<img />");
```

now I can also use handlebars for doing more complex html and attaching it in the above code.

So how can I do the above such things in Angular.js

Please give some examples of some helpful pointers

Comment: you need to display like loading data image or else?

Comment: Even an loading img or a div or p anything, but how to do it ?

Comment: you can use ng-show and ng-hide when it is needed

Comment: what do mean not dynamic? image is static?

Comment: my image or any html will be their in the page, and using ng-hide i am just hiding it, so its not dynamic. I need to replace the image with some content thats dynamic

Comment: Try this one https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: angular.element('#xyz').html('<img />')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `ng-bind-html` like this,

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>

</div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "<img />";
});
```